# I have 27 inch wheels. Will any other tube sizes fit?

Tags: wheels, innertube

I have a bike that has 27x1 1/4 (32-630) wheels. What other tubes will fit?

Answer (score 6):

700x32, usually in a box that says 700x28-32.

Comment: isn't 700c 29", not 27.5"? I thought 27.5" was 650b.

Comment: or is that wheel size not tire size

Comment: @JoshuaF The OP is not talking about 27.5/650b. 27x1 1/4 is rim diameter 630 which is close enough to 700/29" (622 rim diameter) that the tubes are compatible. Tires are not compatible, but tubes are.

Comment: Thanks Noah for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Tubes have a bit of freedom in both directions: both the bead seat diameter of the tire/rim, and also the width of the tire.

Usually you'll see 622 - 28/47 or 622 - 32/47 tubes and when you look at it more carefully, it says 622/635 - 28/47 or 622/635 - 32/47. So those entirely standard tubes for the more common 622mm bead seat diameter work just fine in your application.

My advice about tube sizes: try to pick one where the minimum tire width is very similar to your tire width. So your 32-630 would ideally use 622/635 - 32/47, and only as a second option should use 622/635 - 28/47. The reason is that the less the tube has to stretch, the fewer punctures you will have and also the air leaks slower so you won't have to top up tire pressure every 10 days -- instead, every 14 days might be enough. As a minor drawback, the less the tube has to stretch, the more weight and rolling resistance you have.

So never use a 622/635 - 25/32 "race wide" tube. Even though the 32mm width might suggest it should work, it has to stretch a lot, so you'll get a lot of punctures and also you have to top up the tire pressure very often. A very slightly reduced rolling resistance would be in favor of using these "race wide" tubes, so in a race you would use those, but I suppose from the odd 630mm bead seat diameter that you are not racing.

As a fun fact, I often use 622/635 - 32/47 tubes for a 622-28 tire so nominally the tube is a bit too large, but with enough care in fitting, it fits without wrinkles.

Also remember valve type. Wide rim holes should use Schrader (car valve), narrow rim holes should use Presta (bicycle valve). The odd valve there is Dunlop that fits into a Schrader hole but doesn't work with all pumps so Schrader should be preferred. With suitable grommets and specially shaped washers, it's possible to fit a Presta valve into a Schrader sized hole.

As for the tube material, butyl is preferable, and as thick as possible tube should be preferred. So cyclocross-style "cross" tubes should not be used, instead choose a "tour" tube that is heavier and has more butyl in it. Latex tubes are more expensive and need to be pumped up every day due to the huge air leakage, but as a minor benefit they may reduce rolling resistance a bit.

Comment: Juhist, thanks mate. Your answer was a little more detailed than I would've liked but you have given me insight into what to look for 